How to Calculate Weighted Competing Risks Cumulative Incidence in R?
I am trying to analyze survival data in R by calculating weighted competing risks cumulative incidence for events in a dataset. The dataset includes unique case identifiers, entry times, exposure durations, event indicators, a termination variable, and associated weights. The goal is to replicate the results obtained from similar analyses conducted in Stata. My data is like this:
data <- data.frame(
  case_id = 1:8,
  entry_time = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2),
  exposure_time = c(5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 10, 11, 2),
  event = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2),
  terminated = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  weight = c(1.5, 2.0, 1.0, 0.5, 2.5, 1.2, 1.8, 1.3)
)


Description of Each Column:
case_id: A unique identifier for each case.
entry: The entry variable  records how many months before the start of the study  (or reference period) the individual was already exposed
exposure_time: The duration of exposure for each case
event: A categorical variable indicating the type of event:
1: Event A (failure)
2: Event B (competing risk)
0: Censored (no event occurred by the end of the observation period)
terminated: A binary indicator where 1 signifies that the case is terminated.
weight: The sampling weight
In Stata, I used the following commands:
stset event_time [pweight=weight], failure(event == 1) enter(entry)
stcompet terminated_ = ci, compet1(2)

My code in r is:
# Calculate the time from entry to event
data$event_time <- data$entry_time + data$exposure_time

# Create a survival object for Cox model
surv_obj <- Surv(time = data$event_time, event = data$event)

# Fit the Cox Proportional Hazards Model
cox_model <- coxph(surv_obj ~ 1 +  weight, data = data)

# Summarize the Cox model
summary(cox_model)

# Predict the risk for each case ID
 predict(cox_model, type = "risk")

I have a few questions regarding the calculation of weighted cumulative incidence for competing risks:

Which function in R is used to obtain weighted cumulative incidence for competing risks?
How can I extract cumulative incidence values for each individual case?
How should I apply entry variable for the time variable in analysis?
How should I apply weighting correctly?

Any help on achieving this would be greatly appreciated!
